# Is it possible to have two verbose_names in a Django Model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model that is defined like so...

```
class Message(models.Model):
    email_subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    email = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
```

In want to be able to assign each of those fields two separate verbose_names(one in English, and one in Arabic). So that when I make a ModelForm, and render it to my template... I can do something like this...

```
            {% for field in form %}
                <p>
                    {% if field.field.required %}
                        <label for="{{ field.arabic_verbose_name}}" class='RequiredLabel'>{{ field.name }}</label>
                    {% else %}
                        <label for="{{ field.auto_id }}">{{ field.verbose_name}}</label>
                    {% endif %}

                    {% if field.errors %}
                        <div class='FieldErrorBox'>{{ field }}</div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ field }}
                    {% endif %}
                </p>
            {% endfor %}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You should read https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/

Comment: I know about that was just looking for a more out of the box ready to go solution.,

Comment: Well, you can subclass or monkey-patch `models.Field` to include a second `verbose_name` but I would advise against it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy

class Message(models.Model):
    email_subject = models.CharField(ugettext_lazy('Message field', 'email subject'), max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    email = models.TextField(ugettext_lazy('Message field', 'email address'), null=False, blank=False)
```

Django [internationalization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/i18n/) can take care of this task. Coupled with a package like [django-modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation) can often simplify the task. It's worth doing some [tutorials](http://jonhill.ca/2014/01/11/django-and-internationalization-i18n/) to connect the dots. When using translatable strings in templates, there's tags (generally `{% trans %}`) to be used so that the correct lookups are performed.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but where do we define the the actual translation? Also how do we tell ugettext_lazy what translation to use (arabic or english)?

Comment: Internationalization is a topic to itself, there's a lot there. [Here's](http://blog.bessas.me/post/65775299341/using-gettext-in-django) a good tutorial - Django makes sure to ease the process by providing its own management commands: _makemessages_ that extracts the strings from the source code and _compilemessages_ that converts the files into the binary ones. It also expects to find the PO files for a language under the directory locale/<locale>/LC_MESSAGES/django.po, where <locale> is the language code.